# bash: race condition with pipeline, tee and process substitution

Tags: bash, tee, process-substitution

I want to see `twice` being output twice, but this script will only output it once:

```
dump() {
    (sleep 1; cat) > "$1"
}
(sleep 0; echo "twice") | tee >(dump "./a.txt")
echo "$(< "a.txt")"
```

To see it twice, I have to adjust the sleep time:

```
dump() {
    (sleep 0; cat) > "$1"
}
(sleep 1; echo "twice") | tee >(dump "./a.txt")
echo "$(< "a.txt")"
```

What caused the race condition here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dump` call in the process substitution is running as an asynchronous process.  This means that `tee` writes its output to it, and then the pipelines finishes.  The pipeline finishes because the output from `tee` gets buffered; if you wrote *more data than the size of the pipe buffer*, `tee` would have to wait for `dump` to consume it, and your original code would quite possibly work.

Assuming you only write a small amount of data, as you do in the question, you then read from `a.txt` immediately after the pipeline terminates, before `dump` has had a chance of writing anything to the file (it's still sleeping in the background, with the data hanging around in a pipe buffer).

If you look at the `a.txt` file after running the faulty code, you will notice that it contains the string `twice`. So it does get there eventually, after the slight delay provided by `sleep 1` in the function.

To stop the pipeline from terminating too early, add a `cat` at the end:

```bash
dump() {
    (sleep 1; cat) > "$1"
}

(sleep 0; echo "twice") | tee >(dump "./a.txt") | cat
echo "$(< "a.txt")"
```

This makes it work because now the `cat` process needs to wait for the output of `dump` to arrive over the pipe (there will be none, but it doesn't know that).  This delays the termination of the pipeline until the `dump` call returns.  At that point, the data has already been written to `a.txt` and can be picked up by the last command in the script.

The only thing synchronising the processes in a pipeline is I/O, i.e. reading data from the previous process and writing to the next.  If a process expects to read from the previous step at some point, it will block until something is available to be read, or until the previous step has closed its end of the pipe.

`cat` reads from standard input by default. Standard input of the added `cat` is connected to the standard output of `tee` and to the process substitution with `dump` in the previous step of the pipeline. The `cat` utility will read until there is nothing else to read.  This does not happen until both `tee` and `dump` has finished executing.

---

Cleaned up version of the code:

```bash
dump() {
    sleep 1
    cat >"$1"
}

echo twice | tee >(dump ./a.txt) | cat

cat a.txt
```

Comment: does this mean `echo` only waits for pipeline and `tee` but not `dump`? how can i make `echo` wait for `dump` to finish? i really need this to be synchronous...

Comment: @Cyker See updated answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't feel that this solution is addressing the actual problem: what if `dump` is changed to `dump(){ exec >$1; sleep 1; cat; }`?

Comment: @mosvy Then you have arguably introduced a _new_ problem in a way. You've removed the blocking that `dump` provided so that the `cat` that I added now _for sure_ has no data to wait for from `dump` and can terminate early.

Comment: While I kind of understand what's happening here, could you please be more specific about how your added `| cat` waits for output from both `tee` and `dump`? Where can I find documentation about what that `| cat` waits for *exactly*? (`stdout` being closed?)

Comment: @Cyker Just about right, yes. `cat` waits until its standard input stream is closed. I've added a couple of extra paragraphs to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
(sleep 0; echo "twice") | tee >(dump "./a.txt")
echo "$(< "a.txt")"
```

IIUC, the question is how to wait for the process inside `>(...)` to finish before executing the `$(...)` command substitution from the next line.

The answer is that there's no nice way to do that. If your system supports the `/dev/fd/` mechanism, you could use an `exec fd> >(...)` trick:

```
dump() {
    (sleep 1; cat) > "$1"
}
echo twice | { exec 7> >(dump a.txt); tee /dev/fd/7; exec 7>&-; wait; }
echo "$(< "a.txt")"
```

Yes, that's pretty ugly, but you can do even worse:

```
echo twice | { a=>(dump a.txt); tee "$a"; eval "exec ${a##*/}>&-"; wait; }
```

As it can be gathered for this, **a)** with newer versions of bash (>= 5.0) you can `wait` for the processes run inside `>(...)` and **b)** those processes may not terminate until they get an EOF on their stdin, which will not happen until you close the other end of the pipe -- the `/dev/fd/63` or similar the `>(...)` has expanded to. The latter is quite tricky to get right.

Comment: That `wait` on process substitution looks like a bash 5.0 feature. I'm still on the old version. I guess a `cat` barrier would work in my case, but your `exec >$1` example in the comment shows a great caveat.

Comment: @Cyker The `exec >$1` issue is alleviated by a subshell inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of Bash have a bug such that they do not properly wait for processes spawned by process substitution.